# Ubuntu: Script for check the status of a page and after restart

Tags: unix, ubuntu, http-headers

How can I programmatically check the status of a page in my application? I'd like to be able to reboot the server if I receive a `404`. Is it possible to do this on an automated basis, checking page status at 15 second intervals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```sh
#! /bin/bash
while true; do
    curl --fail --silent http://localhost/your.page >/dev/null 
    if [[ $? -eq 22 ]]; then
        sudo reboot
    fi
    sleep 15
done
```

Check the [curl man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/curl.1.html) for more details

Comment: This is bash. No compiling required

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Is possible to add in the code an elseif for check another page too? Like if one of them have 404 error.. it restart.